# Am I Instantiating an Object from File, when I want to create an ArrayList from File? Java

Tags: java, arraylist, instantiation

We've been assigned to convert a text file into an ArrayList of Geometric Objects. The problem is I don't know if I converted it into an ArrayList or just instantiated an object? Eclipse claims that I haven't used used the ArrayList library

The text file would look something like this:

Circle,red,false,4.0

Circle,blue,true,2.0

Circle,blue,true,10.0

Rectangle,yellow,true,10.0,6.0

Rectangle,green,true,5.0,11.0

Rectangle,red,true,20.0,15.0

I've done this with my code so far:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        GeometricObject g = null;
        File diskFile = new File("e:/temp/obj.txt");
        Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(diskFile);
        while (diskScanner.hasNext()) {
            String list = diskScanner.nextLine();

            g = recreateObject(list);
        }
        diskScanner.close();
    }

    private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String list) {

        String[] data = list.split(",");
        String geoObject = data[0];

        if (geoObject.equals("Circle")) {
            String color = data[1];
            boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(data[2]);
            double radius = Double.valueOf(data[3]);
            return new Circle(color, filled, radius);
        }

        if (geoObject.equals("Rectangle")) {
            String color = data[1];
            boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(data[2]);
            double length = Double.valueOf(data[3]);
            double width = Double.valueOf(data[4]);
            return new Rectangle(color, filled, length, width);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to store each GeometricObject into an "ArrayList list = new ArrayList();" [have not implemented yet] but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Haven't run the code, but it looks like you are reading each line in, making a `GeometricObject` out of it and ... discarding it. So you're close. You need to make a `List<GeometricObject>` and add each object to it as you make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the ArrayList outside of the while loop then add the new object g within the loop...

```
List<GeometricObject> geoList = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
while(diskScanner.hasNext()){
    String list = diskScanner.nextLine();
    g = recreateObject(list);

    geoList.add(g);

}
```

Comment: It's usually a best practice to refer to an object by their interface. In your case List<GeometricObject> geoList = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();

Comment: Whoops that was simpler than I was thinking. Haha, Thanks, I was trying to use .add() methods inside of a for loop and if statements. I have a real problem with simplicity sometimes.

Comment: @shirrine i think when using the diskScanner.hasNext() method its cutting out the last line of the .txt file.

Comment: Hmmm... What are you seeing? Or not seeing? LOL

Comment: Okay nevermind, I've got dumb brain. My showObjects method was wrong. My mistake, apologies. I'm in a panic mode right now but thanks Thanks for your help!